# VNC Server for non-Jailbroken iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm looking for a VNC server for my iPhone/iPad that (assuming I know the IP address) I can connect directly to using a VNC client. To summarize the features I'm looking for:

- Non-hosted, i.e. no software needed to be continuously running on a computer (rules out  [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) or [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/))
- Non-Jailbroken device (rules out [Veency](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A VNC server on an un-jailbroken device is impossible due to Apple restrictions.** Any such app would not be able to run in the background (without a jailbreak tweak to modify the backgrounding code) and is not permitted by App Store regulations anyway.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the answer.

Answer (score -1):

EggPlant (testing tool) can run a vnc server on iOS device without jail breaking, though I have no clues, how they do them. Thanks